# Uninstall PostgreSQL BigSQL Distro 10.5.1

Tags: postgresql, windows-installer

Have installed the [BigSQL PostgreSQL distro version 10.5.1](https://www.openscg.com/bigsql/postgresql/installers.jsp/).

Wanted to uninstall from a Windows 10 machine.

Using Add/Remove programs; error message on remove =>

> Unable to locate uninstall.dat

I can find the uninstall.dat file in:

%installdir%\uninstall\uinstall.dat (194Kb)

It is residing there with an uinstall.exe.

When running the uninstall.exe, still same message

> Unable to locate uninstall.dat

Have tried randomly moving the uninstall.dat up a level to:

%installdir%\

Still no joy.

Have tried re-installing (stop service, rename %installdir%, then running install again).

Still same error:

> Unable to locate uninstall.dat

I have also tried Microsoft's "Program Install / Uninstall Troubleshooter", but the installation doesn't even show in the list, and I can't find a product code.

Any suggestions on how I can remove this (I want to install the EnterpriseDB distrobution instead).

Comment: It seems that a couple of others have posted answers indicating that they too have run into the same issue; but it seems that the question has now been 'protected' and those 'answers' removed. Just noting that here so any others that come along know that this doesn't appear to be an isolated issue.